# Creating a mock S3Response object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a piece of code that calls S3 API and it returns an object of [S3Response][1Ω type. But I want to create this `S3Response` object manually without calling the S3 API. How can I do that?

As far as I tested, the `S3Response` class does not expose any methods that you can use to instantiate an object and populate the values. But at the end of the day, this is just another Java object so I'm guessing there is some way of creating an `S3Response` object from scratch without dealing with the S3 API.

Comment: Yes, please do tell us why your want to do this?

Comment: My use case is pretty specific. I have an API call that requires my account to be whitelisted. I have added a new change that doesn’t depend on the result of the API call but the call is still made. So this was to just implement my change without needing to go through the approval step.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but there are many implementations using the builder pattern you can use for example:

```
S3Response response = CreateBucketResponse.builder(). /*...*/ .build();
S3Response response = CopyObjectResponse.builder(). /*...*/ .build();
S3Response response = AbortMultipartUploadResponse.builder(). /*...*/ .build();
...
...
```

You can find the full list of implementations in the documentation [Package software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Although I could swear that I already tried this before but wasn’t successful.